# How to show several subviews?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I'm having what I think is a bit of a newbie problem... 
I've made a dynamic scroll view where images and labels are programmatically added as subviews. Problem is that only the last one I'm adding as a subview is showing.
Also when I read about "addSubview:" it says "Adds a view to the end of the receiver’s list of subviews." Does this mean only the last added subview is supposed show? In that case how do I make both visible?

Thanks in advance,
Tom

CODE:

```
for(int i = 0; i < [famorableArray count]; i++){

    UIButton *famorableButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [famorableButton setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 5.0f, 57.0f, 57.0f)];
    [famorableButton setImage:personLogo forState:UIControlStateNormal]; 

    NSString *famString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[[famorableArray objectAtIndex:i] substringFromIndex:8] capitalizedString]];
    NSLog(@"%@", famString);
    UILabel *famLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    famLabel.text = famString;
    NSLog(@"Test2 %@", famLabel.text);

    // Move the buttons position in the x-demension (horizontal).
    CGRect btnRect = famorableButton.frame;
    btnRect.origin.x = totalButtonWidth;
    [famorableButton setFrame:btnRect];

    CGRect labelRect = famLabel.frame;
    labelRect.origin.x = totalButtonWidth + 28.5f;
    [famLabel setFrame:btnRect];


    // Add the button to the scrollview
    [famScroll addSubview:famLabel];
    [famScroll addSubview:famorableButton];

    // Add the width of the button to the total width.
    totalButtonWidth += famorableButton.frame.size.width + 30;

}
[famScroll setContentSize:CGSizeMake(totalButtonWidth, 79.0f)];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad... It was a fail editing after copy paste. Accidentally used btnRect as a frame for the label too. Thanks for your effort anyways @Martin :)

Answer (score 1):

For each added subview you have to set the `frame` property. The frame is the view's position in the superview. "Adding to the list of subviews" does not imply any automatic layout. So I assume that all your subviews are visible but overlap.

Comment: also the scrollView.contentSize needs to be set - this will be a CGPoint with width equal to (typically) the sum of the added views width (for horizontal scroll) and height equal to the added view height.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add code... Putting it in the original post.

Think I have everything you said though...

Comment: Wasn't allowed to post my own answer within 7 hours but heres what I tried to write: 

My bad... It was a fail editing after copy paste. Accidentally used btnRect as a frame for the label too.

Thanks for your effort anyways @Martin :)